# How to call hide on the returned value from jquery select

Tags: javascript, jquery

My DOM structure looks like:

```
  <div class="weather-Dashboard"></div>
    Dashboard
    <div class="weather-Charts">
      charts
    </div>
    <div class="weather-Statistics">
      Statistics
    </div>
    <div class="weather-Sites">
      Sites
    </div>
```

I want to select each `div` dom which class contains `weather` and hide them  with jQuery. Below is my JS code:

```
var e = $('div[class *= "weather"]');
e.each(function() {
  console.log(this);
  this.hide();
});
```

After run this code I got below error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.hide is not a function

It seems that `this` is not a jQuery object. What's wrong with my code? I have tried if there is only one DOM match the query, I can call `e.hide()` to hide the dom. However it doesn't work for the case when there are multiple DOM matches.

Comment: *"if there is only one dom match the query, I can call e.hide() to hide the dom"* - You can call `e.hide()` to hide any and all elements that matched your selector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because `this` refers to a DOMElement which does not have a `hide()` method. You need to wrap `this` in a jQuery object first:

```
var e = $('div[class*="weather"]');
e.each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

However you should note that you don't need an `each()` loop here - you can call `hide()` directly on the collection:

```
$('div[class*="weather"]').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method `this` refers to DOM object and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) is a jQuery method so you need to convert it to jQuery object.

```
$(this).hide();
```

Or simply update the `display` style property.

```
this.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var e = $('div[class *= "weather"]');
e.each(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="weather-Dashboard"></div>
      Dashboard
  <div class="weather-Charts">
    charts
  </div>
  <div class="weather-Statistics">
    Statistics
  </div>
  <div class="weather-Sites">
    Sites
  </div>
```